# Is there a way to "stream" data from Google Cloud Platform to Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, stream, cloud, iot

I am using GCP to manage IOT devices using IOT Core. The incoming telemetry triggers a cloud function which stores the data in Firestore.

I have been asked to send the telemetry to an Azure SQL database. I am not familiar with Azure but, with the products that both GCP and Azure provide, there must be a way to get this right.

The device sends an update to GCP once per minute.

My initial thought was to use a cloud function to "pass" the data on to Azure when it is received in GCP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Azure have many IoT services but for a message per minute, they are overkill for your scenario.  While they are many ways to achieve your goal, one would be to create a Google Cloud Function that will send the data each minute to an Azure Function.  That function would then save the data to your Azure SQL Database.

Comment: That sounds promising. I've used HTTP functions with GCP before and it seems like Azure Functions can be used in the same way. Would HTTP be the best choice for sending data between functions? Are there any obvious alternatives to HTTP?

Comment: HTTP is the obvious choice.  Other triggers exist but for Azure services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp